# Compiler affects head files、 "using namespace std;"? And the running speed?

Tags: visual-c++

After searching the faq, there is no questions similar to mine.
I used visual c++ to program this morning. I used to begin with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and there is no problem. But now, after I reinstall visual c++, it just couldn't work, and after compiling, it will display an error:
**d:\visual c++\vc6en\vc98\include\ios(9) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'streambuf': No such file or directory
Error executing cl.exe.**
But I'm sure "streambuf.h" exists and the path is right.
So I begin with:

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and it works! Why? What's the differences between these two ways and how they affect things will be different?
There is one more question. After reinstalling visual c++, the speed it runs a program becomes very very slow, even a very simple program. Before, running a program only takes no more than 3s, but now, it even takes 30s. What's the reason?

I want to know the anwsers very much. I'll appreciate it when you sovle my problems.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio did you have before and what version did you reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ 6 was notorious for not following standards and being generally buggy.  I strongly suggest, if you are going to use Visual C++, get the latest release (Visual C++ 2010 Express is available for free).  You'll find that many modern programs have issues with the VC6 compiler, and using a newer version will encourage you to learn modern standards compliant C++.

`<iostream.h>` is the deprecated, nonstandard header, while `<iostream>` is in the standards. For a full discussion on the differences, see [here](http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html).